# Drool DRL contains

Tags: drools

This my When condition

```
$cla : cashliquidassets(
  entity == "AU001",
  asset_liability_indicator == "A",
  product_group.contains('Loans','Bankofindia'),
  product.contains("DS"),
  counterparty_resident_indicator == "AU",
  counterparty_type.contains("DS"),
  related_entity == "Y"
)
```

I am getting an error at

**Unable to Analyse Expression product_group.contains("Loans","Bankofindia")**

Any Suggestions

Answer (score 1):

Without your class model is hard to tell, but assuming that `cashliquidassets.product_group` is a `String`, you are trying to use an unexisting method `String.contains(String, String)`.

One option would be to use an `OR` or and `AND` between 2 `contains`:

```
...
(product_group.contains('Loans') || product_group.contains('Bankofindia')),
...
```

or

```
...
product_group.contains('Loans'),
product_group.contains('Bankofindia'),
...
```

Another option could be to use the [matches operator with a regular expression](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/latest/drools-docs/html_single/#_the_operator_code_matches_code).

Hope it helps,